# Virtual memory limit on linux based ARM

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management, arm

I try to allocate memory using calloc(). The maximum size I can get is 1027 Mb (not 1024 Mb). I see this from the top command output. ulimit -v is set to unlimited. imx6q ARM. How can I allocate more memory? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SU! Two things: 1.Wrong forum - go to StackOverflow 2. Always show your source code (what have you already tried)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a 32-bit addressed architecture, theoretically you could use at most 4 GiB of virtual memory. Parts of them, however, is either reserved for kernel or allocated to hold library and program code, so it's possible you're left with less than 2 GiB of memory.